# Why is my search method not working? Java

Tags: java, search

I am making a program that calculates the tax owed for 20 CEO's. I am trying to add a search function using a linear search but it says "xxx not found" every time. Anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code. The search method is at the end of the code. and please keep in mind I'm sill a beginner. Thx

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
// The "CEO" class.
public class CEO
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader X = new BufferedReader (new FileReader    ("G://CEO.txt"));

    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter ("taxinfo.txt");
    PrintWriter Y = new PrintWriter (outFile);

    String line;
    double taxrate;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {

        line = X.readLine ();
        String[] textarray = line.split (",");


        String name = textarray [0];

        String company = textarray [1];

        String salary = textarray [2];

        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        String namear[] = name.split (",");

        String companyar[] = company.split (",");

        String salaryar[] = salary.split (",");

        String salary2 = String.valueOf (salaryar [0]);

        double salary3 = Double.parseDouble (salary2);


        //////////////////////////////////////////

        if (salary3 <= 10000000)
        {
            taxrate = 40;
        }
        else
        {
            taxrate = 53;
        }

        calcTax (salary3, taxrate);

        Y.println (namear[0]);
        Y.println (companyar[0]);
        Y.println ((long) salary3);
        Y.println (calcTax (salary3, taxrate));
        Y.println ("");
        System.out.println (namear[0] + ", " + companyar[0] + ", $" + (long)salary3 + ", $" + (calcTax (salary3, taxrate)));

        if (i == 19)
        {
            String findMe;

            findMe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter name to search");

            int loc;
            loc = findName (findMe, namear);
            if (loc >= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, namear[loc]);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, findMe + " not found");
            }
        }
    }
    Y.close ();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Records stored in file");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



} // main method


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static double calcTax (double salary, double taxrate)
{
    double taxowed = 0;

    taxowed = (salary * taxrate) / 100;

    return taxowed;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static int findName (String nameToFind, String array[])
{
    int place = -1;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        if (nameToFind.equalsIgnoreCase (array [i]) == true)
        {
            place = i;
        }
    }
    return place;
}
} // CEO class
```

Comment: The code looks OK to me.  I think the problem is in the input, probably a misspelling of one of the names.  I think you should trace this out in a debugger.

Comment: always try to use the debugger before asking!

Comment: (Actually I see something that looks incorrect: I don't think `namear` is being initialized correctly.  However, if your input data is different than I'm expecting, maybe it is, so again it's back to a debugger to make sure all the values in `findName` are as you expect.)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do some impossible things with your Strings.

```html
String[] textarray = line.split (",");
...
String name = textarray [0];
...
String namear[] = name.split (",");
```

There is no possibility of `name` containing any `,`, since `name` comes from a String already split by `,`.

Let's say you have a line `John,Smith,Company,Name` and you split it by `,` -> result is gonna be an array `[John, Smith, Company, Name]`, and now you are trying to split `John` - that just can't give you what you want.

Comment: If this is the problem, the OP should be able confirm it quickly by running the above code in a debugger.  Time for the OP to learn to use one!

Comment: Would be a perfect world if anyone could just start up a debugger. I myself could only do that few years after I started programming, so I understand why some people may not be able to. That's why I sometimes answer such questions, I just understand the pain. Of course I'm talking about hardware limitations, IDE + debugger requires a lot of power.

Comment: For a simple problem like this, a debugger is ideal.  For larger code, logging statements (or even just `printf`s) are usually preferred, as steping though many lines of code can be labor intensive.  Also, if your code can only be run inside some larger code base (say a huge web app) it's usually better to refactor or re-write portions so that you can test/debug without having the entire production environment available.

Comment: I tried to run it and it worked. this is the output (name,company,salary,tax)

Comment: Example first line:  Louis Vachon,  National Bank of Canada, $10500000, $5565000.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok thx guys, I figured it out....

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
// The "CEO" class.
public class CEO
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader X = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("D://CEO.txt"));

    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter ("taxinfo.txt");
    PrintWriter Y = new PrintWriter (outFile);

    String line;
    double taxrate;
    String salary2;
    double salary3;

    String names[];
    String cnames[];
    String salary[];
    String taxesowedstr[];

    names = new String [20];  
    cnames = new String [20];
    salary = new String [20];
    taxesowedstr = new String [20];

    for (int k = 0 ; k < names.length ; k++)
    {
        line = X.readLine ();
        String[] textarray = line.split (",");
        names [k] = textarray [0];
        cnames [k] = textarray [1];
        salary [k] = textarray [2];
        salary2 = String.valueOf (salary [k]);
        salary3 = Double.parseDouble (salary2);

        if (salary3 <= 10000000)
        {
            taxrate = 40;
        }
        else
        {
            taxrate = 53;
        }


        Y.println (names [k]);
        Y.println (cnames [k]);
        Y.println ((long) salary3);
        Y.println (calcTax (salary3, taxrate));
        Y.println ("");
        System.out.println (names [k] + ", " + cnames [k] + ", $" + (long) salary3 + ", $" + (calcTax (salary3, taxrate)));

        double taxes = calcTax (salary3, taxrate);

        taxesowedstr [k] = String.valueOf (taxes);

        if (k == 19)
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Records stored in file");

            String findMe;

            findMe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter name to search");

            int loc;
            loc = findName (findMe, names);
            if (loc >= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, names [loc] + ", " + cnames [loc] + ", $" + salary [loc] + ", $" + taxesowedstr [loc]);
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, findMe + " not found");
            }
        }

    }

    Y.close ();

} // main method


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static double calcTax (double salary, double taxrate)
{
    double taxowed = 0;

    taxowed = (salary * taxrate) / 100;

    return taxowed;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public static int findName (String nameToFind, String array[])
{
    int place = -1;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        if (nameToFind.equalsIgnoreCase (array [i]) == true)
        {
            place = i;
        }
    }
    return place;
}
} // CEO class
```